# Seeking tools to analyse 23andme raw data?

Tags: dna, software-recommendations

I recently got my ancestry genetic test done from 23andme. I am interested in finding out more about my raw data.

Does anybody know of some good tools that come for a good price and give me the maximum information?

I have already tried Promethease and I am looking for something that I can understand by myself.

Comment: This question could be improved if we knew more about what specific questions you have. "Anything I can learn" is both too broad and unclear.  See the [help] for more information about our site, including https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask If you wanted more information about the results you got from Promethease, your question shouldn't have been migrated here.

Comment: Is there a Genealogy aspect to your question?  If so, can you provide more details about what that is, please?  If not, we will need to close which will reject the migration from the [health.se] Stack Exchange. Our [help] describes what is on-topic here.

Comment: If you are just seeking software recommendations, then your question may be better asked at the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You are not being very specific with regards to what it is you expect to find out about your raw data.

Currently 23andMe and Living DNA use the [new V5 chip](https://blog.23andme.com/news/23andmes-new-custom-chip/). As a result there are fewer tools available to work with it than with the raw data of other companies.

There's 3 things use can use your raw data for:

1. If you want to find out what DNA relatives match to portions of it, or what ethnicity estimates come from it, then 23andMe itself gives you that information, and [you can upload your V5 raw data to](http://thednageek.com/whats-new-in-autosomal-dna-transfers/) GEDmatch Genesis, DNA.Land, Living DNA and WeGene, all of which have their own features and give you different matches and/or estimates.
2. If you want to find out what health information it contains, 23andMe provides excellent health reports. [Promethease](https://promethease.com/) is a program you can upload your raw DNA to for $10 that creates a personal DNA report based on your DNA data using information from [SNPedia](https://www.snpedia.com/). Alternatively, you can use SNPedia itself and check out manually what each of your SNPs mean.
3. If you want to analyze the raw data for its properties and patterns, you could try [David Pike's utilities](https://www.math.mun.ca/~dapike/FF23utils/). There are also a number of other [3rd party tools listed at 23andYou](http://www.23andyou.com/3rdparty), but I have not personally tried any of them with 23andMe data so I cannot tell you if they're any good or not.